# How to run a batch file that has foreign language text?

Tags: batch-file, unicode

I want to make a batch file that copies files from a folder to another folder, and the destination folder has Persian characters.

when I want to save the code in text doc it says that it have to be saved in Unicode, but Unicode doesn't work in batch file.

How can I do it?

The code is:

```
copy "C:\Users\arm" "C:\Users\عکس"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to install **Microsoft Language distribution package** on your computer. It will allow your computer to read and write worldwide languages on your computer. after that you can use Persian character in anything(Folder name, File Name, Text content, Batch file etc.)

Comment: thank you,But is there any way? because i do not have access to install anything on my PC at my work.

Comment: That is the only way.